# Scrolling line pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'd like to continuously plot sensor data, and occasionally draw vertical lines to represent events. I can get the sensor data to scroll, but I'm not sure how to scroll lines offscreen after using `addLine` to add them, and the plot ends up looking like this:

[image]

The line stays in place at the edge of the plot (at the time that I wanted to draw it) while the real plot gets more and more compressed.

Here's my code:

```
ptr = 0
acc_data = deque(maxlen=window_width)
plot = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
acc_plot = win.addPlot(title="Accelerometer Data")
acc_curve = acc_plot.plot()

while True:
    data = await websocket.recv()
    data = json.loads(data)
    if data["event"] == "accelerometer":
        data = data["data"]
        acc_data.append(float(data["x"]))
        ptr += 1
        acc_curve.setData(acc_data)
        acc_curve.setPos(ptr, 0)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
    elif data["event"] == "press":
        acc_plot.addLine(x=ptr, y=None)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

How can I make the line scroll with the plot (and eventually offscreen once the time is far enough in the past)?